# How to return pointer of a std::pair from map and put it to vector<*std::pair...>

Tags: c++

As title says, how can I get specific pair pointer from my map and put it to vector?
Here is my code:

```
std::map<std::string, Object*> scene_objects;
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Object*>*> scene_objects_layers;

scene_objects_layers.insert(scene_objects_layers.begin(), scene_objects.find(*object->getName())); //not working
```

Comment: `scene_objects_layers` is not a vector of pointers.

Comment: and what is object ? and what are the error messages

Comment: I edited it. It's now pointer.

Comment: You need to post real code instead of fantasy code. `std::vector<*std::pair<std::string, Object*>> ` is not valid C++.

Comment: This is wrong: `std::vector<*std::pair<std::string, Object*>>` try `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Object*>*>`.

Comment: Object is just an random class.

Honestly, I don't understand point of this site. Is this site just for posting fancy and perfect questions or site for geting answers on questions. Every time I post a question, someone must comment something totaly not related to my question and ofcourse give me this unlike or minus whatever it is. If it's true this site is just for fancy questions, then I will instantly leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::map::find` returns an *iterator*. An iterator can be dereferenced with the unary `*` operator. This will give you a *reference* to the `value_type` of the map. You can take an address of that to make a *pointer*.

Thus,

```
    &*scene_objects.find(object->getName())
```

will create the pointer you need.

Comment: Absolutely do not do this. The lifetime of any pairs whose address is taken this way is at most the lifetime of the map. As soon as the map goes out of scope, everything you stored in the vector will become invalid. There aren't even guarantees that modifications to the map will preserve all the original pairs. In fact, there are no statements at *all* about how long pointers obtained this way will remain valid. You're pretty much just asking for a seg fault here. cc @Petar

Comment: @JasonC  "The lifetime of any pairs whose address is taken this way is at most  the lifetime of the map" Yes, so?.  "There aren't even guarantees that modifications to the map will preserve all the original pairs" There are. "There aren't even guarantees that modifications to the map will preserve all the original pairs" There are. "The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container,
and the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements"

Comment: What do you mean "yes, so?". We dont know enough about the ops situation to know if it's appropriate, and you don't mention it as a caveat because you seem to insist on speaking in incomplete riddles. If you're going to give an unsafe and poor answer, at least include the important caveats in it so nobody takes it to heart and wonders why their application crashes later. Don't give advice that only works in very specific situations without describing those situations, that's just irresponsible, and a disservice to readers.

Comment: I mean yes, the lifetime is limited, and we don't know enough about the ops situation to know if it's appropriate. It's for OP to decide.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. If you read the `map` documentation you will see that nothing returns pointers to pairs. And there's not really anything that returns references to pairs with a useful lifetime, either.

So either store actual pairs in your vector (is there any real reason to use pointers to pairs?), or create copies of the pairs with `new pair...`.

Comment: *nothing returns pointers to pairs* But something returns an iterator.

Comment: And what can you do with an iterator?

Comment: @n.m. I'll tell you one thing you can't do with it: Store it in a vector of pointers to pairs. If you have something relevant to say, say it. If you have a question about iterators, post it.

Comment: Just did, take a look.

Comment: @n.m. Dereference it?

Comment: @RawN yes, exactly.

Comment: When references to the pairs get invalidated is defined by the standard.

Comment: It is neither temporary nor short-lived. It is as good as the iterator you get it from.